# R ifelse label plotting

Tags: r, if-statement, plot, label

I am trying to plot a graph in R and I only want the labels of the nodes to be printed if the label is either '`blue', 'red', 'purple', 'green'`

Here is my current line of code to perform the plot:

```
plot(g, layout = layout.auto, vertex.size=0, vertex.label=
         ifelse((V(g)$label == 'red' || V(g)$label == 'blue' || V(g)$label == 'purple' || V(g)$label == 'green'), V(g)$label, NA),
         edge.arrow.size=.1, main=infile)
```

The result is that no labels are printed at all. If I only have one of the cases (no || symbols) then it will print the proper label.

1. How do I get the specified functionality?
2. Why does it appear that the `test` parameter to `ifelse` will not work with a `||` symbol?

Thanks for all the help?

Comment: Reproducible example? What is `g`, `V`, `layout.auto`, 'infile`? Also, look at the function `%in%`.

Comment: Try vectorized OR `|` instead of logical OR `||` (returns a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`).

Comment: Also, perhaps `V(g)$label %in% c('red','blue','purple','green')` as your condition in `ifelse`.

Comment: vectorized OR worked! Thanks!